# How to link from a jQuery tab to another tab? (specific jQuery Tabbed Interface)

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, linker, internal

I'm working on a site that uses this specific jQuery tab interface:

http://www.queness.com/post/106/jquery-tabbed-interfacetabbed-structure-menu-tutorial

I was asked to make a link on tab 1, that opens for example tab 4 (it has to behave as I would click directly on tab 4, so without reloading the page). I have tried everything that I can think of. I also searched a couple of hours for a solution or a hint, but everything I found was not applicable on this tab system.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Ondrej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way regarding your code would be:

```
$('#tabMenu li').eq(2).click()
```

For example, if you want to link to the second tab, use this:

```
<a onclick="$('#tabMenu li').eq(2).click()">Click it</a>
```

Notice that eq() starts with 0. So for example eq(4) selects the fifth tab.

Comment: Works like a charm! I only added a href="javascript:;", because of the missing pointer cursor. However, there is one small issue - I just realized, that the site uses two separate tab interfaces under "tabMenu". That means, that if I click on the link, it takes me to the 4th tab as it is supposed to, but it also deselects the default selected tab on the second tab interface. The best solution would be probably to place the 2nd tab menu for example under "tabMenu2" or am I mistaking?

Comment: Exactly. Notice that you assigned a id to two elements. This is not very good. Every id should be unique. If you change it to tabMenu2, the CSS styling for `tabMenu` will not apply. You can solve this problem by using classes instead of id's. Classes don't have to be unique. It's very simple: Instead of `id="tabMenu"`, you use `class="tabMenu"` and instead of using `#tabMenu` you use `.tabMenu`. This way you don't have to copy/paste/duplicate your code. You can assign id's and classes. It might be difficult for now, but I'm sure you will find out how it works by yourself.

Comment: Well, the page isn't my project, I was only asked to make some internal tab-links. I know how ids and classes work :) However, I changed the 2nd interface id to tabMenu2, because there were some unforeseen problems with the classes and the additional 1kB is not worth the time. And of course - thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI Tab Widget has a [select method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select):

so you can just insert a link that call that method on the tab container

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#myDiv').tabs('select',2)">Switch Tab</a>
```

Comment: Yes, the original one has this function, it is also explained in the description, but this tab system has no anchors assigned for the li, so it doesn't work.